# pandas pre-filter an exploded list

Tags: pandas, list, pandas-explode

I have a list column in a pandas dataframe that needs to be exploded and filtered based on another list.

```
df_have = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['emp_1', 'emp_2', 'emp_3', 'admin'],
                        'group_ids': [[5, 3], [4, 2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]})

> df_have
    user        group_ids
0  emp_1           [5, 3]
1  emp_2        [4, 2, 3]
2  emp_3           [1, 4]
3  admin  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I have tried the below:

```
df_have = df_have.explode('group_ids')
selected_ids = [2, 3]
df_want = df_have[df_have['group_ids'].isin(selected_ids)]

> df_want
    user group_ids
0  emp_1         3
1  emp_2         2
1  emp_2         3
3  admin         2
3  admin         3
```

This gives the correct output, but is very slow when `group_ids` column is more than 100, and the `selected_ids` are usually less than 5 groups at a time.

My question is: is there a way to pre-filter and explode only the **values** within the groups that have the `selected_ids`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to pre-filter, with a `set` of the values as reference:

```
selected_ids = [2, 3]
S = set(selected_ids)

out = (df.assign(group_ids=[[x for x in l if x in S] for l in df['group_ids']])
          .explode('group_ids').dropna(subset=['group_ids'])
      )
```

Output:

```
    user group_ids
0  emp_1         3
1  emp_2         2
1  emp_2         3
3  admin         2
3  admin         3
```

Comment: Thanks, this mostly works, but returns `emp_3` with a `NaN` value for me though

Comment: Strange, exploding an empty list should delete the row. Which pandas version do you use? You can always `dropna(subset=['group_ids'])` as a workaround.

Comment: `python` 3.9.14 and `pandas` 1.4.3. I know dropping NaNs after the explode will work, was hoping there'd be a way to just not explode those users at all though seeing as efficiency is important here. If not, happy to accept this answer.

Comment: @Grizzly2501 actually my bad, this is an [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39915), so yes `dropna` or use `loc` but it's likely not as efficient

Comment: sadness.. thanks for this though, it already helps quite a bit